# angular style not applied on components (despite the use of host selectors)

Tags: angular

I have an issue with the styling of components in my angular projects. I can't get it to work basically. To explain my issue I created a new project using Angular CLI (CLI 6.0.8, angular 6.1.0). Right off the bate I create a new test component in which I declare the following things:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - 
COMPONENT TEMPLATE FILE:
- - - - - - - - - - - - - 

<div>with div</div>
without div

- - - - - - - - - - - - - 
COMPONENT STYLE FILE:
- - - - - - - - - - - - - 

:host
{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

(no changes to the typescript declaration file)

I include this component in the app template, and declare some styling for it in the app.css file too:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - 
APP TEMPLATE FILE:
- - - - - - - - - - - - - 

<app-test class='test'></app-test>

- - - - - - - - - - - - - 
APP STYLE FILE:
- - - - - - - - - - - - - 

.test
{
  background-color: red;
  width: 350px;
}
```

This is the result I get:

[IMAGE : style does not apply correctly (background color applies to the free text only)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybTmu.png)

[IMAGE : the width of the element is not updated and the element size is not shown as it usually is when using chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNW42.png)

[IMAGE : usually element sizes are highlighted in blue when shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf3rB.png)

As shown in the images, the styling is not applied correctly, whether it is defined in the parent scope or in the component scope (using :host). Styles are updated but not shown. When I change the 'app-test' tag into a 'div' tag in the browser (using the debug tools > edit as HTML), it is displayed correctly:

[IMAGE : changing the angular component tag into a div tag sorts the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM9JQ.png)

I reckon it has something to do with the way angular displays the component since changing the tag to a DIV works. But I don't understand where this problem comes from. This issue appears on a newly created project using CLI, without configuration anything in the project config...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

About the width issue your facing in the test component, assuming you want the whole element to span to a width of 350px, you should define its display property to block:

```
:host {
  background: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

Custom elements does not have a default display property and your browser can't guess what your means are.

About applying the `.test` style on your component, the `app-component` styles are encapsulated using the `_nghost-c0` and `_ng-content-c0` attributes and therefor not being applied on `test.component`. If you want to apply the `.test` on other components you can either write the **CSS RULE** on the global `styles.css` file which is applied globally:

```
//styles.css
.test {
  background-color: red;
  width: 350px;
}
```

or use the `viewEncapsulation` property on your `@component` decorator like this:

```
//app.component.ts
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

and then you can leave the **CSS RULE** on the `app.component` file

```
//app.component.css
.test {
  background-color: red;
  width: 350px;
}
```

but now the styles in that file are not encapsulated and will penetrate other components.

Comment: Oooh! That's the display thing! I use display: flex nearly everywhere, so I have generally no problem, but sometime the styles on host weren't applied and I didn't understand why. Now, I know!

Answer (score 4):

Its because custom components (custom html tags) are rendered as inline elements.

use

```
:host
{
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

And it will work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hknw2a?file=src/app/app.component.scss

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your child inside a div and apply the css to the div

```
<div class="test">
  <app-child></app-child>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to avoid this workaround if possible. Firstly because it adds unnecessary HTML tags, secondly because it does not sort this problem entirely. Doing so would allow me to style the child component from the parent scope, but not from the child scope. My main problem is that :host does not work as expected...