# Leaflet divIcon not displaying on map in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, markers

I am trying to add a divicon marker in angular leaflet.

component.css:

```
.leaflet-div-icon2
{
    background: #e5001a;
    border:5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    color:blue;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:50%;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

component.ts :

```
var map = L.map('map', {
        attributionControl: false,
        crs: L.CRS.Simple
});

var bounds = [[0,0], [1000,1000]];
var image = L.imageOverlay('cust_image.png', bounds).addTo(map);
var customMarkerIcon = L.divIcon({className: 'leaflet-div-icon2'});

var m3 = L.latLng([ 348,278.2]);
L.marker(m3, {icon: customMarkerIcon }).addTo(map);
```

I am not getting any error in console but unable to view the marker on the map.

It works on basic html page w/ css and js but not in angular.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I met a similar issue recently. Use `divIcon` in an angular component, And try to style it divIcon in the css file of the component. But the style can't be added to the divicon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure why it is not working for you but you need to place the code **inside ngOnInit lifecycle hook** and  L.divIcon class selector style **inside global styles.css**. Here is a similar example with what you are trying to achieve:

app.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const map = L.map("map", {
      crs: L.CRS.Simple
    });

    const bounds = [[0, 0], [1000, 1000]];

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    const image = L.imageOverlay(
      "https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/uqm_map_full.png",
      bounds
    ).addTo(map);
    const customMarkerIcon = L.divIcon({
      className: "leaflet-div-icon2"
    });

    const m3 = L.latLng([348, 278.2]);
    L.marker(m3, {
      icon: customMarkerIcon
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

styles.css:

```
.leaflet-div-icon2 {
  background: #e5001a;
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wqn0zpz8jk)

Comment: "L.divIcon class selector style inside global styles.css" - this solved it. Is there an explanation as to why?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51616307/4929531) and [this](https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-encapsulation-with-angular-components). I modified also the demo to see it live.

Comment: This is both awesome, and bizarre.  I was expecting the class to show up on the icon, even if the styling wasn't there, but maybe leafletjs checks if the styling exists (and only on the global scope).  Global styling fixed it with leafletJS@1.9.4